# Textbook grader says my output doesn't match but I can't find where my error is

Tags: java

This grader is really finicky and I've spent 30 minutes trying to find where the error is and I can't find it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class FileLetterCounter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
        String filename = scan.nextLine();
        File afile = new File(filename);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(afile);
    
        System.out.print("Enter character to count: ");
        char character = input.next().charAt(0);
    
       String line;
       int count = 0;
    
       while (input.hasNext())
        {
            line = input.nextLine();
            for (int a=0;a<line.length();a++)
            {
               if (line.charAt(a)==character) 
               {
                   count++;
               }
            }
        }
         input.close();
         System.out.printf("The character '%c' appears in the file %s %d times.", character,       filename, count);
     }

 }
```

This is what it should look like:

```
Enter file name: mydata.txt
Enter character to count: a
The character 'a' appears in the file mydata.txt 17 times.
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
 Checking output
 Your standard output is not what was expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the character you should enter should be from the standard input. This line is using the file as the input for the character.

```
char character = input.next().charAt(0);
```

Your standard input scanner is `scan`.

Comment: So change it to:
    char character = scan.next().charAt(0); ?

Comment: Right. How does that work out for you?

Comment: That didn't work out for me, but I appreciate the help.